# how to connect to source with the overlay filter?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I want to create overlay filters to the inputs.

I have 2 mp4 video and want to make 1 to left and 1 to right.

according the example in docs of ffmpeg I create filters of overlay
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/6.0/decode_filter_video_8c-example.html

the example do not create overlay filter and I created one.
`const AVFilter* video = avfilter_get_by_name("overlay");`
`ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&filter_ctx, video, "overlay", NULL, NULL, filter_graph);`

but the `avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)` returns error:

> Input pad "main" with type video of the filter instance "overlay1" of
> overlay not connected to any source

it seems that the filter I created not connect to the video source.

how to connect to the video source?